# How does DBpedia live extractor work?

Tags: wikipedia, dbpedia

How does DBpedia live updater (extractor) work? Does it go over all changes in Wikipedia and update their correspondences in DBpedia?
I updated some Wikipedia articles (Both article body and infobox)that have corresponding entries in DBpedia and kept monitored them in DBpedia along with changeset for days, but they were not updated.

Answer (score 1):

The main http://dbpedia.org/sparql endpoint doesn't get updated live from the Wikipedia firehose.  It gets a periodic batch update produced from and made available as dumps.

For the live firehose updates, you can use --

- http://dbpedia-live.openlinksw.com/sparql
- http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql

And these pages will give you an idea of their activity levels --

- http://dbpedia-live.openlinksw.com/live/
- http://live.dbpedia.org/statistics/

There do appear to be a couple of issues there at present.  You'll generally get faster responses about such by writing the [dbpedia-discussion](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/dbpedia-discussion) and/or [virtuoso-users](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/virtuoso-users/) mailing lists directly.

(ObDisclaimer: I work for [OpenLink Software](http://www.openlinksw.com/), producer of [Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/), and provider of the DBpedia endpoint.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I forgot to mention that I'm using DBpedia live endpoint. I will contact the mailing list and keep this thread updated.